# Magento 1 Config Product Add to cart working for first product only

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute, addtocart

Hello,

I have just read csv file and add product to basket but first product adding perfectly with attributes. The issue is starting with second product it is not add to cart with attributes.

Hope you are helping to me. Can you please whats wrong with the code?

```
foreach ($skus as $key=>$value) {

    $productNew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$value);
    $addItionalProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $value);
    if($addItionalProduct == ''){
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Sku of "'.$value.'" Not Found.');
    }else{
        try{
            $productId = $addItionalProduct->getId();
            $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
            $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

            if($addItionalProduct->getVisibility() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE){

                $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
                $pid = $parentIds[0];
                $configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
                $productAttributeOptions = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurableProduct);
                $options = array();

                foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
                    $allValues = array_column($productAttribute['values'], 'value_index');
                    $currentProductValue = $addItionalProduct->getData($productAttribute['attribute_code']);
                    if (in_array($currentProductValue, $allValues)) {
                        $options[$productAttribute['attribute_id']] = $currentProductValue;
                    }
                }
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $configurableProduct->getId(),
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'super_attribute' => $options
                );

                $product->load($configurableProduct->getId());
                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);


            }else{
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $productId,
                    'qty' => 1,
                );
                $product->load($productId);
                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem.The cart is not reinitialize so that it shows only simple product

Below code you have to help.

```
foreach ($skus as $key=>$value) {

$productNew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$value);
$addItionalProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $value);
if($addItionalProduct == ''){
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Sku of "'.$value.'" Not Found.');
}else{
    try{
        $productId = $addItionalProduct->getId();
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

        if($addItionalProduct->getVisibility() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE){

            $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
            $pid = $parentIds[0];
            $configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
            $productAttributeOptions = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurableProduct);
            $options = array();

            foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
                $allValues = array_column($productAttribute['values'], 'value_index');
                $currentProductValue = $addItionalProduct->getData($productAttribute['attribute_code']);
                if (in_array($currentProductValue, $allValues)) {
                    $options[$productAttribute['attribute_id']] = $currentProductValue;
                }
            }
            $params = array(
                'product' => $configurableProduct->getId(),
                'qty' => 1,
                'super_attribute' => $options
            );

            $product->load($configurableProduct->getId());
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);


        }else{
            $params = array(
                'product' => $productId,
                'qty' => 1,
            );
            $product->load($productId);
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){

    }
}
}
```

Thanks